# Entity framework Query with Top keword on child table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

```
 var countries= ctx.Country
                .Include("cities") // I want to take only 10 cities. How to take top 10 cities and city name starts from "A"
                .Include("Schools")            
                .Where(x => (x.CountryID == 100))
                .ToList();
```

1 - Top 10 ciites 
2 - Where criteria on CityName field

I am using Entity Framework 6

Comment: Adding `Take` should work for TOP(n) query: `.Where(x => x.CountryID == 100 && x.CityName.StartsWith("A")).Take(10).ToList()`.

Comment: I only want to apply Take on cities not on schools or Countries

Comment: CityName is field of City table

Comment: What happens if you add `&& x.City.CityName.Startwith("A").....` to your `take`?

Comment: @oerkelens - CityName gives compile time error. but it works fine like  ctx.Cities.CityName

Comment: @oerkelens  - Not working like this .Where(x.City.CityName.Startwith("A").Take(5))
But Works if ctx.City.Where(x.CityName.Startwith("A").Take(5))

Comment: I read that you can't do filtering on Include: `.Include("cities").Take(n)` doesn't work. Use a projection instead of `Include`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - What will be the projection query?

Comment: Somewhat like this: `var countries = ctx.Country.Select(x => new { CountryID = x.CountryID, ..., Cities = x.Cities.StartsWith("A").OrderBy(c => c.CityID).Take(10), Schools = x.Schools}).Where(x => x.CountryID == 100).ToList()`. Instead of using `Include`, use `Select` for parent entity & query child entities inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
var countries = ctx.Country.Select( c => new { 
                        Country = c,
                        Cities = c.Cities.Where(ci = > ci.CityName.ToLower().Startwith("A".ToLower())).Take(10),
                        Schools = Cities.select(ci => ci.Schools)
                  }).Where(x => x.CountryID == 100).ToList();
```

I didn't test it, maybe you will get some compile errors, cuz i don't know how you named your classes.

Let me know if you need any clarification or have any question

Answer (score 0):

Set up the navigation property relationships between country, school, and city then select a structure based on the data you want to receive into an anonymous type and let EF handle the query composition.

```
var countryData = ctx.Countries
  .Include(x => x.Schools)
  .Where(x => x.CountryID == 100)
  .Select(x => new { Country = x, Cities = x.Cities.OrderBy(c => c.CityName).Take(10).ToList() })
  .ToList(); // This likely only returns 1 row due to the CountryId Where Clause...
```

This will give you a structure containing the Country reference and the list of up to 10 cities associated to each country.

If you access the Cities collection on a Country object in the results you will still lazy-load all cities, but the .Cities collection returned in the above statement would be the 10 you care about.

If there are a lot of cities in a country and loading this complete set is potentially expensive then you may want to consider leaving the entities disconnected so rather than having a Cities collection associated to a country, treat cities as a top-level entity that happens to have a relationship to country. (I.e. City mapping `.HasRequired(x=> Country).WithMany()` rather than mapping a `.HasMany(x=> x.Cities).WithRequired(x=>x.Country)` on the country.)

This would change the query somewhat if you want more than one country, by using a GroupBy expression, though it'd only return countries that had at least one city based on the search criteria.